# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 con java

Tags: java, sql

No logro encontrar el sentido a este error, ya que se supone que debe haber un error insertando datos dentro de la database...

```
private static void exitAction() throws IOException, SQLException {
        setExitHour(dtf.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
        String month = dmf.format(LocalDateTime.now());
        String day   = ddf.format(LocalDateTime.now());

        ConnectionClass connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        Connection connection = ConnectionClass.getConnection();

        String sql ="INSERT INTO Control VALUES('"+getName()+","+getStartHour()+"')";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);

        App.stop();
    }
```

Se supone que insertando los valores tipo String (ambos dos, inclusive la fecha, ya corregiré ese error intencionado más adelante) en las columnas de la database con tipo VARCHAR, debería poder insertarlo sin el más mínimo problema, sin embargo, no se hace.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Con solamente un campo, en concreto, name, si que me deja, no lo entiendo.

Comment: Consejo: mejor usá `preparedStatement`, que tu consulta es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL :D

Answer (score 1):

Vale ya lo vi, era problema de las ''...

Con esta sentencia:

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO Control VALUES('"+getName()+"','"+getStartHour()+"')";
```

Todo solucionado, faltaban las comillas simples, cometí un error bastante tonto.